# Planning the calculation of progress percentages in the Progress Bar

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, frontend, progress-bar, software-design

I need to plan and implement the calculation of progress bar based on this object that i received from the backend :

due: {
coref: 1,
extract: 4,
keyconcepts: 1,
question-text-cmas: 1,
question-text-fibq: 1,
question-text-mcq: 1,
rank: 1,
summary-1: 1,
text: 1,
topic: 1
}

I already build the progress bar component, now i need to think of this impelementation.

This is the function that i started to implement :

```
const propertiesRef = useRef({
    extract: { curr: 0, max: 15 },
    keyconcepts: { curr: 0, max: 20 },
    question: {
        cmas: { curr: 0, max: 10 },
        fibq: { crr: 0, max: 10 },
        mcq: { curr: 0, max: 10 },
    },
    rank: { curr: 0, max: 5 },
    summary: { curr: 0, max: 15 },
    text: { curr: 0, max: 10 },
    topic: { curr: 0, max: 5 },
    allOver: 0,
}); // In this object i'll save the progress

const getProcess = async () => {
    let conditionLoop = true;
    do {
        setTimeout(async () => {
            await axios
                .get(`Route`, { withCredentials: true }) //From here i get the due object
                .then((res) => {
                    conditionLoop = res.data.due;
                    if (res?.data?.due) {
                        for (let key in propertiesRef.current) {
                            if (res.data.due.hasOwn(key)) {
                                console.log(key, res.data.due[key]);
                            }
                            if (res.data.due.hasOwn("question-text-cmas")) {
                                console.log(res.data.due);
                            }
                            if (res.data.due.hasOwn("question-text-fibq")) {
                                console.log(res.data.due);
                            }
                            if (res.data.due.hasOwn("question-text-mcq")) {
                                console.log(res.data.due);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        propertiesRef.current.allOver = 1;
                        conditionloop=false;
                    }
                    console.log(propertiesRef.current);
                });
        }, 2000);
    } while (conditionLoop);
};
```

This happens in my app while i generate some unit summary.

Important to say : When each property is done, it removed by the backend from the due object, and each property that have value 1 means that it still pending, when it's more than 1 it means that it is in progress.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A simple minded solution would be to just remember the first due count, and compare it to the current one.

Something like this:

```js
let totalProgress = useRef(null);
let progressFraction = useRef(null);

const progressFetchInterval = 2000;

const getProgress = async () => {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    await axios.get(`Route`, { withCredentials: true }).then((res) => {
      fraction = getFraction(res);
      getFraction.current = fraction;
      if (fraction === 1) totalProgress.current = null;
      else getProgress();
    });
  }, progressFetchInterval);
};

const getFraction = async (res) => {
  // ... request validation code ...
  const dueMap = res.data.due;
  const dueCount = Object.values(dueMap).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  if (totalProgress.current === null) totalProgress.current = dueCount;
  return (totalProgress.current - dueCount) / totalProgress.current;
};
```

Comment: It remains on 15.